# Can two related "spends" be in the same block?

Tags: transactions, block

Consider the case where:

- Address **A** has some BTC.
- Address **B** is empty/zero.
- Address **C** is the intended recipient.

**B** sending to **C** is invalid on its own, but does make sense if associated with **A** sending to **B** first

Can two dependent transactions be put into the same block and accepted?

- **A** ==> **B**
- **B** ==> **C**

*(Since the net result will be OK, even though the second transaction does not make sense until the first one is completed)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but only if `A -> B` is placed before `B -> C` in the list of transactions.

[Here](https://transactionfee.info/charts/inputs-and-outputs-same-block-spends/) is a graph of the percentage of transactions spending each other in the same block, it is usually around 10%.

Comment: So even within a block, there is a strict ordering of transactions?  I had been under the impression that blocks were ordered, but transactions within a block were unordered!  Very interesting. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, there are a substantial amount of such transactions :) Slightly related: https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/611 discusses those transactions as UTXOs created and spent in the same block reduce the size of the proofs

Comment: @abelenky No, there is no strict ordering, at least for Bitcoin. The answer states one of the three requirements: 1) this answer 2) the coinbase tx comes first 3) no duplicate/invalid/double-spend transactions. There are usually multiple possible orderings satisfying these requirements.