# Chain 2 transactions in same block with bitcoinlib in Python

Tags: transactions, utxo, python-bitcoinlib

I asked yesterday if it's possible to have a tx from A to B then B to C in the same block, with the second tx spending the UTXO of the first one (with initial balance of B is 0)

Apparently it is : [Can two related "spends" be in the same block?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/101206/can-two-related-spends-be-in-the-same-block)

But now i'm trying to test this with bitcoinlib in Python.
My code is :

```
wallet = Wallet.create('MyWallet',
                        keys = seed_phrase,
                        witness_type = "segwit")

address = wallet.get_key(0).address
address2 = wallet.get_key(1).address
address3 = wallet.get_key(2).address

wallet.transactions_update()

fee = 1_000
send_value = wallet.balance() - fee

tx = wallet.send( [(address2, send_value)],
                    fee = fee,
                    offline = True)

wallet.transaction_import(tx)

send_value2 = send_value - fee

tx2 = wallet.send( [(address3, send_value2)], 
                     account_id = 1,
                     fee = fee,
                     offline = True)
```

The first tx work correctly because the first address have a balance, but then the second one fail with :

```
WalletError: Create transaction: No unspent transaction outputs found or no key available for UTXO's
```

I think the problem is with the importation of the first tx in the wallet

Any idea on how to fix this ?
Thank you

Comment: I have a couple ideas someone may want to investigate if they’re writing an answer: (1) It looks like the `account_id` parameter allows you to manage multiple accounts within one wallet. You only specify `account_id` on the second transaction, but not on the first. What happens if you drop the `account_id` parameter? (2) The library may not support spending unconfirmed funds.

Comment: (1) account_id is zero by default, if i remove it for the second tx then it send from address 0 to address 2, not what i want (2) yeah probably, if i wait for the first tx to be confirmed in the blockchain then it works, but it takes too long to wait for new blocks

Comment: Have you considered testing on testnet, regtest, or signet?

Comment: no i tested this on mainnet directly, i think the library will do the same with testnet